# Post GraphQL mutation with Python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests, graphql

I'm having trouble posting mutations with GraphQL and Python Requests.

My function looks like:

```
def create(request):
    access_token = 'REDACTED'
    headers = {
        "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": access_token
    }


    mutation = """
    {
      checkoutCreate(input: {
        lineItems: [{ variantId: "Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0VmFyaWFudC80", quantity: 1 }]
      }) {
        checkout {
           id
           webUrl
           lineItems(first: 5) {
             edges {
               node {
                 title
                 quantity
               }
             }
           }
        }
      }
    }
    """

    data = (requests.post('https://catsinuniform.myshopify.com/api/graphql', json={'mutation': mutation}, headers=headers).json())


    print(data)
    return render(request, 'Stock/create.html', { 'create': data })
```

I'm getting errors saying I have a bad request "bad_request - Parameter Missing or Invalid" in my json response.

Comment: Please take care to omit sensitive information like credentials or tokens/keys when posting question and answers.

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens. You can also edit out the info and flag your post for a moderator to redact the edit history.

Comment: BIt late on this Samuel!

Answer (score 6):

Even though you're sending a mutation, your request body should still include a query property, the value of which should be the string representing your operation. It's a bit confusing, but informally both queries and mutations are called "queries" (you're still "querying" the server either way). Change your request to:

```
requests.post('https://catsinuniform.myshopify.com/api/graphql', json={'query': mutation}, headers=headers)
```